# Devise 401 Unauthorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, devise

I'm using Ruby 4.2.3 and Devise 4.2.0 and I'm trying to sign in using POST method ($resource AngularJS) but 'I'm getting 401 Enauthorized error ('You need to sign in or sign up before continuing')

I'm following this [Documentation](http://blog.sundaycoding.com/blog/2015/04/04/token-authentication-with-tiddle/) which is working fine if I try outside my app. For instance using 'Postman'.

Alright, some code:

My angular controller to send the log in data to server:

```
$scope.log_in = function(){
        sendData = new Sign_in($scope.user);
        sendData.$save(null, function(response){
          $cookies.put("user_email", $scope.user.email);
          $cookies.put("user_token", response.data.authentication_token);
        }, function(error){
            console.log('error log in');
        });
    }
```

my session devise controller (as exactly as the tutorial)

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def create
    user = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    token = Tiddle.create_and_return_token(user, request)
        render json: { authentication_token: token }
  end

  def destroy
    Tiddle.expire_token(current_user, request) if current_user
      super
    #render json: {}
  end

  private

    # this is invoked before destroy and we have to override it
    def verify_signed_out_user
    end
end
```

my postman example that shows that is working:

[image]

What am i missing? I try to look out all around but I couldn't find any updated info. Any guide you could recommend?

Thanks!

Edit:
Sign_in

```
function Sign_in($resource){
    var sign_in = $resource('sign_in/.json', {id: '@id'});
    return sign_in;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the Sign_in model?

Comment: edited, its a factory actually.

Comment: Why is it `sign_in/.json`? Shouldn't it be `sign_in.json`?

Comment: either way... the same error still occur... My head is about to explote. There is any other documentation or video to follow up?

Comment: I'm not sure what the bug is, but I can help you debug.  
Is the angular request being sent to `localhost:3000/users/sign_in`?